# Putty segmentation fault

Tags: 17.10, putty, segmentation-fault

I have just installed PuTTY with `sudo apt-get install putty` command.

When I try to run it, I immediately receive `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @SDsolar Ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Recommend you check the system software then retry.

**Here's the procedure:**

```
sudo apt-get remove putty
```

- Open Software Updater and let it check for updates.  If there are any, let it apply them, including reboots as necessary.
- Then run it again just to make sure there are no updates to the updates.

---

Then go through this sequence of commands:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get install putty
```

---

**Then try it again.**

---

FYI, just checked the Snap Store for Putty:

https://snapcraft.io/search?q=putty

And it reports there is not a Snap version available.

Comment: Thanks, got it working. The problem was that my package manager wasn't working properly due to incorrect repository names in /etc/apt/sources.list file. I also needed to upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS